# Cocoon cocoon:after-insert coffee script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-chosen, cocoon-gem

I have a nested form using Cocoon. Within the nested form I have a select menu that I want to call chosen() on.

Normally I would have the following in the code

```
$('#cust_select').chosen()
```

However, I need to call this after a nested field has been added using something such as

```
    $('#container').bind('cocoon:before-insert', function(e, inserted_item) {
      // ... do something
    });
```

However, I can't get this to work and so have 2 questions

1. what is the coffee script version of this code?
2. is inserted_item the actual code to use or should item be replaced with the model name?

any thoughts?

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** The CoffeeScript version is:

```
$('#cust_select').chosen() # just the same

$('#container').bind 'cocoon:before-insert', (e, inserted_item) -> 
  # ... do something with the inserted item
```

**2)** inserted_item is indeed the inserted item:

From [here](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items)

> To listen to the events, you to have the following code in your javascript:
>
> ```
> $('#container').bind('cocoon:before-insert', function(e, inserted_item) {
>    // ... do something
> });
> ```
>
> Where e is the event and the second parameter is the inserted or removed item. This allows you to change markup, or add effects/animations (see example below).

Comment: Great thanks. worked a treat. slowly getting my head around coffeescript!